# How to run 2 similar Javascript functions on the same page

Tags: javascript

I have a page that is split into sections and 2 of the sections show images. At first I wanted to show a static image in one section and a rotating image in the other which I have done. But I would now like to have both sections running their own set of rating images, so rotator1 would show images 1-6 and rotator 2 would show images 7-12. With some trial and error I can get it so that section 1 shows rotator 1 and then section 2 show rotator 2 and then goes back to section 1 and so forth.

I would like to get section 1 and section 2 to show their rotators at the same time.

Below are the extracts of my code so far:

```
<div id="pay-slides">

<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function(){
            window.displayImgCount = 0;
            function cycleImage(){
                if (displayImgCount !== 0) {
                    document.getElementById("img" + displayImgCount).style.display = "none";
                }
                displayImgCount = displayImgCount === 6 ? 1 : displayImgCount + 1;
                document.getElementById("img" + displayImgCount).style.display = "block";
                setTimeout(cycleImage, 5000);
            }
            cycleImage();
        }


    </script>

    <img id="img1" src="E:\HTMLCustomerDisplay - Shop\app\img\pay-image1.jpg" style="display: none">
    <img id="img2" src="E:\HTMLCustomerDisplay - Shop\app\img\pay-image2.jpg" style="display: none">
    <img id="img3" src="E:\HTMLCustomerDisplay - Shop\app\img\pay-image1.jpg" style="display: none">
    <img id="img4" src="E:\HTMLCustomerDisplay - Shop\app\img\pay-image2.jpg" style="display: none">
    <img id="img5" src="E:\HTMLCustomerDisplay - Shop\app\img\pay-image1.jpg" style="display: none">
    <img id="img6" src="E:\HTMLCustomerDisplay - Shop\app\img\pay-image2.jpg" style="display: none">
</div>


<div id="adv-slides">

<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function(){
            window.displayImgCount = 0;
            function cycleImage(){
                if (displayImgCount !== 0) {
                    document.getElementById("img" + displayImgCount).style.display = "none";
                }
                displayImgCount = displayImgCount === 12 ? 7 : displayImgCount + 1;
                document.getElementById("img" + displayImgCount).style.display = "block";
                setTimeout(cycleImage(), 5000);
            }
            cycleImage();
        }
    </script>

    <img id="img7" src="E:\HTMLCustomerDisplay - Shop\app\img\adv-image1.jpg" style="display: none">
    <img id="img8" src="E:\HTMLCustomerDisplay - Shop\app\img\adv-image2.jpg" style="display: none">
    <img id="img9" src="E:\HTMLCustomerDisplay - Shop\app\img\adv-image1.jpg" style="display: none">
    <img id="img10" src="E:\HTMLCustomerDisplay - Shop\app\img\adv-image2.jpg" style="display: none">
    <img id="img11" src="E:\HTMLCustomerDisplay - Shop\app\img\adv-image1.jpg" style="display: none">
    <img id="img12" src="E:\HTMLCustomerDisplay - Shop\app\img\adv-image2.jpg" style="display: none">
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Peter.

Answer (score 0):

There is two major problems in you code.  First, you are overriding the onload handler.  You need to wrap your two functions in a parent function and then place it on the onload.  Second, you are abusing global scope and clobber your state.  This can be seen with the two uses of `window.displayImgCount`.  Thirdly, keep your image ids separate for easier to debug code.

```
<div id="pay-slides">

<script type="text/javascript">
        function initPaySlides(){
            //window.displayImgCount = 0;
            var displayImgCount = 0; //scoped to this function
            function cycleImage(){
                if (displayImgCount !== 0) {
                    document.getElementById("imgPay" + displayImgCount).style.display = "none";
                }
                displayImgCount = displayImgCount === 6 ? 1 : displayImgCount + 1;
                document.getElementById("imgPay" + displayImgCount).style.display = "block";
                setTimeout(cycleImage, 5000);
            }
            cycleImage();
        }


    </script>

    <img id="imgPay1" src="E:\HTMLCustomerDisplay - Shop\app\img\pay-image1.jpg" style="display: none">
    <img id="imgPay2" src="E:\HTMLCustomerDisplay - Shop\app\img\pay-image2.jpg" style="display: none">
    <img id="imgPay3" src="E:\HTMLCustomerDisplay - Shop\app\img\pay-image1.jpg" style="display: none">
    <img id="imgPay4" src="E:\HTMLCustomerDisplay - Shop\app\img\pay-image2.jpg" style="display: none">
    <img id="imgPay5" src="E:\HTMLCustomerDisplay - Shop\app\img\pay-image1.jpg" style="display: none">
    <img id="imgPay6" src="E:\HTMLCustomerDisplay - Shop\app\img\pay-image2.jpg" style="display: none">
</div>


<div id="adv-slides">

<script type="text/javascript">
        function initAdvSlides(){
            //window.displayImgCount = 0;
            var displayImgCount = 0; //scoped to this function
            function cycleImage(){
                if (displayImgCount !== 0) {
                    document.getElementById("imgAdv" + displayImgCount).style.display = "none";
                }
                displayImgCount = displayImgCount === 6 ? 1 : displayImgCount + 1;
                document.getElementById("imgAdv" + displayImgCount).style.display = "block";
                setTimeout(cycleImage(), 5000);
            }
            cycleImage();
        }

        window.onload = function(){
          initPaySlides();
          initAdvSlides();
        }
    </script>

    <img id="imgAdv1" src="E:\HTMLCustomerDisplay - Shop\app\img\adv-image1.jpg" style="display: none">
    <img id="imgAdv2" src="E:\HTMLCustomerDisplay - Shop\app\img\adv-image2.jpg" style="display: none">
    <img id="imgAdv3" src="E:\HTMLCustomerDisplay - Shop\app\img\adv-image1.jpg" style="display: none">
    <img id="imgAdv4" src="E:\HTMLCustomerDisplay - Shop\app\img\adv-image2.jpg" style="display: none">
    <img id="imgAdv5" src="E:\HTMLCustomerDisplay - Shop\app\img\adv-image1.jpg" style="display: none">
    <img id="imgAdv6" src="E:\HTMLCustomerDisplay - Shop\app\img\adv-image2.jpg" style="display: none">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How you use this code is upto you :) this is a start

```js
        window.onload = function() {
          window.displayImgCount = 0;
          window.displayImgCount1 = 7;

          function cycleImage() {
            if (displayImgCount !== 0 && displayImgCount1 !== 0) {
              document.getElementById("img" + displayImgCount).style.display = "none";
              document.getElementById("img" + displayImgCount1).style.display = "none";
            }
            displayImgCount = displayImgCount === 6 ? 1 : displayImgCount + 1;
            displayImgCount1 = displayImgCount1 === 12 ? 1 : displayImgCount1 + 1
            console.log(displayImgCount);
            console.log(displayImgCount1);
            document.getElementById("img" + displayImgCount).style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("img" + displayImgCount1).style.display = "block";
            setTimeout(cycleImage, 5000);
          }
          cycleImage();
        }
```

```html
<div id="pay-slides" style="border:1px solid">
  <img id="img1" src="http://www.desireerumbaugh.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Slider_withAndrew.jpg" style="display: none">
  <img id="img2" src="http://www.desireerumbaugh.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Slider1.jpg" style="display: none">
  <img id="img3" src="http://www.desireerumbaugh.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Slider5.jpg" style="display: none">
  <img id="img4" src="http://www.desireerumbaugh.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Slider_YJWisdomWarriors.jpg" style="display: none">
  <img id="img5" src="http://www.desireerumbaugh.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Slider_prayer.jpg" style="display: none">
  <img id="img6" src="http://www.desireerumbaugh.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Slider5.jpg" style="display: none">
</div>


<div id="adv-slides" style="border:1px solid">
  <img id="img7" src="http://www.desireerumbaugh.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Slider_withAndrew.jpg" style="display: none">
  <img id="img8" src="http://www.desireerumbaugh.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Slider1.jpg" style="display: none">
  <img id="img9" src="http://www.desireerumbaugh.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Slider5.jpg" style="display: none">
  <img id="img10" src="http://www.desireerumbaugh.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Slider_YJWisdomWarriors.jpg" style="display: none">
  <img id="img11" src="http://www.desireerumbaugh.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Slider_prayer.jpg" style="display: none">
  <img id="img12" src="http://www.desireerumbaugh.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Slider5.jpg" style="display: none">
</div>
```